# Sync my files to my webserver through ftp using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ftp, synchronization

I have been using vb.net for a while. I am trying to figure out if there is a way that i can update file in a given folder to ftp and get any file on server back using vb.net

Is this Rocket Science or is it ok for intermediate programmer? Where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your needs for simple upload/download FtpWebRequest is enough.

If you however plan to **list** files/folders, compute **checksums** you can try [Ftp.dll FTPS 
component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/ftp/).

```
Using ftp As New Ftp
    ftp.ConnectSSL("ftp.server.com")
    ftp.Login("user", "password")

    ftp.ChangeFolder("uploads")
    ftp.Upload("report.txt", "c:\report.txt")

    Dim serverHash As Byte() = client.GetFileHash("report.txt", FtpHashType.CRC)

    ftp.Close()
End Using
```

Please note that this is a commercial product I created

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `FtpWebRequest` class.